# Можно ли сделать модификацию функции Эйлера?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, теория-чисел

Как известно, функция Эйлера ищет количество взаимно простых чисел с N на отрезке [1..N]. Мне же необходим поиск взаимно простых чисел с N на отрезке 1..K, где K <= N.
Если такое можно сделать, то возьмите за исходник вот этот код:

```
long EilerF(long n) 
{
    long result = n;
    for (long i=2; i*i<=n; ++i)
        if (n % i == 0) 
        {
            while (n % i == 0)
                n /= i;
            result -= result / i;
        }
    if (n > 1)
        result -= result / n;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: что касается асимптотики, то можно 2sqrt(N), но не больше.

Comment: Это будет количество чисел от 1 до K, где `gcd(K[i], N) == 1`.

Comment: с таким вариантом я Time Limit словлю.

Comment: Я не могу додумать свою идею.. Хочу все простые множители N запихнуть в set<>, а потом уже поработать с этим set'ом и что-то от чего-то отнятью

Answer (score 2):

Собственно это не такая простая задача как кажется. 
Количество чисел взаимно простых с n из отрезка [1..k] выражается формулой [image: Формула]

m(d) это функция Мебиуса
Вот здесь показано как ее вычислить.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-mobius-function/

Второй множитель это функция "пол". Ближайшее снизу целое для вещественного числа floor(1.5)=1, floor (1.1)=1.

Собственно нужно пройти по всем делителям числа N и подсчитать указанную сумму. Из функции Эйлера это не получится.